# Upgrade to Google Play Services:9.0.0 Error Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I upgraded my build.gradle file from

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

and now I am getting this error that I wasn't getting before.

**Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your Google Repository in the SDK Manager?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Google Repository = 26

Comment: Hmmm... when I look at the POM for `play-services:9.0.0` in my SDK, I do not see `play-services-measurement` as a dependency, and there is no `9.0.0` of `play-services-measurement`. Are you manually requesting `play-services-measurement`? If not, try cleaning the project, or doing a command-line `gradle` build with the `--refresh-dependencies` switch, to try to get it to stop looking for `play-services-measurement`. On the whole, though, you are probably better off using the more-focused dependencies (the ones you have commented out) rather than the "kitchen sink" `play-services` one.

Comment: 1. I am not requesting the play-services-measurement at all, no where in my code. 2. I switched to "kitchen sink" play-service because of this error. 3. I may have to do this refresh which I have never done before.

Comment: I don't use the command line to often, how do I go about refreshing the dependencies via cmd line?

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9
.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom

Comment: Assuming that the answer below does not solve your problem, you need to determine what is trying to load that dependency (and, in particular, that version). `play-services` no longer requires it, as of 9.0.0, so something else must be asking for it.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

This was found to fix the problem.

Update your classpath in project level gradle `com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0` to classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`

Comment: If someone doesn't find it... this change must be made in the top level build.gradle.... this worked for me but then I got this error "Missing api_key/current_key object", so I had to apply this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/37317752/50730

Comment: I get the old error "Attribute "orientation" has already been defined". Updated google-services classpath to 3.0.0. And enabled GCM and added Server API key tat is generated in google-services.json file.  Could anybody help me ?

Comment: Now the error has changed to "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFreeDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing api_key/current_key object" ???

Comment: With respect, can someone explain exactly why this "fix" works?  I find the quality of SO answers that just give a recommendation, without pointing to docs or core reasons for the original failure, to be barely helpful, and potentially lead to more confusion.

Comment: still getting error Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0.
Required by:
    app_1:app:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>

Comment: For those that didn't get the point of update: it is into build.gradle of the project root (inside the dependencies tag), not the app one. :)

Comment: Hi I got com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0

but why does my Android Studio still asks for 9.0.0

Comment: I have version 3.0.0 but got the same error. I don't think this can fix the root of the issue.

Answer (score 27):

**[Required: Latest versions of Android Studio and Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project)**

You can add the plugin to your project by updating your top-level **build.gradle and your app-level build.gradle** files as follows:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

**Like**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Now, you need to add a dependency for Google Play Services. Inside your app's **build.gradle** add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

**Finally**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "// set Yours"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I get 'Could not download Google-services.jar (com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0)

Comment: That link offers no other advice than what you gave, and the link is outdated. The version numbers have changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: @AndrewS please provide your `build.gradle` . You can ask this as question .

Comment: @AndrewS please check my edited answer . after that `clean-rebuild-gradle`

Answer (score 11):

GCM has been `rebranded` to `Firebase` Cloud Messaging (FCM), If you want to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0` read this article [FCM](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).
Do this maybe work, modify your `build.gradle` file to use the plugin.

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error however `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing api_key/current_key object`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal solve this problem by generate google-service.json https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: I had to import my project into firebase console and regenerate the google-service.json file for it to work for me. Import your project into firebase and then click on 'manage' you can then download a new file if the above does not work for you

Comment: Why **3.0.0**?  Isn't that an old version.  I believe we are on **9.4.0** already.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you dont neet to chagne 3.0.0 just update 9.2.1 to 9.4.0

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky version 3.0.0 is for gradle plugin, 9.4.0 is for library

Comment: How do you update `com.google.android.gms`  to version `9.2.0` in linux ??
SDK Manager is not showing any update, so I'll have to update manually

Comment: @mrid I'm from iran i just use proxy server and sdk manager show any updates to me.. if google developer limits your country just use proxy

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way I found is to use the latest version for all.**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //Firebase
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6' //10.2.6
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6' // used for FCM
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6' // used for FCM
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

**EXPLAINATION**

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Add this at bottom.

- First,  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` // Add this at bottom.
- Then, add these into dependencies

  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'` // make suere this is in latest version.

  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'` //10.2.6 Latest

  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'` // used for FCM

  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'` // used for FCM

*Suppose if you have firebase-auth 10.2.6 that is latest today 25, May 2017, But simultaneously you're using play-services-auth:9.0.0 or below than latest, then they both can't make the connection and show you the error.*

**I hope this helped.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this tricky problem by changing the string in Gradle to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0' //or latest version
```

Answer (score 0):

When changing play services to a version above 10.2.1 my dependencies started to fail resolving.

I found out that changing the following maven URL solved the issue:

```
maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onepf/OPF-mvn-repo/master/' }
```

to

```
maven { url 'https://github.com/onepf/OPF-mvn-repo/raw/master/' }
```

It might that the URL change avoids a cache it in gradle or maven and that resolves it.