# Missing api_key/current key with Google Services 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Since I upgraded the project with the latest version of google services and libraries (9.0.0), I have this strange issue :

[image: Error build]

Grade console :

```
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/cyrilmorales/Documents/Projects/mobilemeans-punainenristi/app/google-services.json
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing api_key/current_key object
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

build.gradle (root) :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle (app) :

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

However, it works well with the play service libraries in 8.4.0 and google-services 2.1.0

Do you have any idea of the solution ?

Comment: I am using maps and I have api_key defined in AndroidManifest.xml file. Have you got api_key there? Something like that 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdRVxThQsNaqY" />

Comment: Yes, I have it. The Manifest is well configured, it always worked .. until now.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Generate new config file (google-services.json) from: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config

Newly config file with `"api_key": [ { "current_key": XXX } ]` in client section

**Update:** or manually enabled service in developer console and generate key.

Comment: I already tried this morning, it doesn't fix the problem even if I noticed small changes with my old google-services.json and the new one.

Comment: Newly is in conf file "api_key": [
        { "current_key": XXX
        }
      ]

Comment: Which API key should go there?

Comment: From https://console.developers.google.com  > Credentials and create API key for Android.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I actually put in my build.gradle file one row in the release section:
resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", VALUE_OF_RELEASE_API_MAPS_KEY
and another in the debug section:
resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", VALUE_OF_DEBUG_API_MAPS_KEY

and a placeholder in the AndroidManifest:
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />

So it puts the right value once the app is launched. What should I put in the "api_key": [ { "current_key": XXX } ] field in google-services.json?

Comment: I tried putting the release key and the debug one as well, doesn't work:       "api_key": [{ "current_key": "ApemSyBll61Ij0Swz1mbGz4rZzxquSacbHIajir" }],

Comment: You must enable Cloud Messaging even if you don't use it and generate a new json file. When you enable Cloud Messaging you get the API key need it for it.

Comment: @RafaelGutiérrez Tried this but did not get any value here ("api_key": []). Cloud messaging + Analytics is enabled. Must be something else. Maps? Any bug posted at Google for this?

Comment: In my case when I add this new service the key was automatically inserted in the file, and also, Google Api Console create a new credential called "Android key (auto created by Google Service)" with the same key.

Comment: I got the API key in the JSON file by enabling the Cloud Messaging API

      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "the_api_key"
        }
      ],

but still doesn't work. I don't really know what's wrong with it.  :-/

Comment: Do you have the new key in Google API Console?

Comment: Yes, I got the new Key for Cloud Messaging in the Google API console

Comment: I too have same issue. Updated google-services classpath. And enabled GCM and added Server API key tat is generated in google-services.json file. I get the old error "Attribute "orientation" has already been defined". Could anybody help me ?

Comment: I've tried generating the json file again. Same error

Comment: It does work now, I get notifications, but I also get 2 errors in my log: "FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement" and "FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found."

Comment: I was able to create the new config with the api_key parameter, but the IDE is still complaining that it is missing api_key

Comment: For some reason simply regenerating the file (though it was a little different) didn't add the API key. But I added it manually and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You may have to disable 'Google Cloud Messaging' first from here ( https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/googlecloudmessaging/overview?project=_ ). Then generate the config file from here ( https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config ).

Comment: Who knows what this api_key is for? It worked fine without it before...

Comment: @PavelBiryukov Were you able to find the use of API key? Is the the GCM API key or Google Maps or something else?

Comment: It seems for FireBase messaging
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder

Comment: it redirects to console in that FCM and in my app i need google plus login also so what can i do please help befor gplus is working coming its not working

Answer (score 91):

Adding empty current key value in google-services.json file solved this problem for me

`"api_key": [{ "current_key": "" }]`

Comment: Just thought I'd add that the "api_key" value is inside the "client" value

Comment: @Ajax -the Max:  This worked for me too.  Could you be so kind as to explain why this works?

Comment: this seems to best solution if utilising old GMS cloud messaging. New config file excludes GMS key instead adding Firebase.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, as for the first time using with Firebase, i face like that.Click on your app menu and click "Manage".

[image]

you can download google-services.json again.

[image]

Comment: yes i downloaded it again and it was bigger file the next time and this fix the issue for me

Comment: I can confirm: I signed up for Firebase Analytics and it automatically downloaded a google-services.json containing no API key. Then i downloaded it manually like this and the API key was in the json.

Comment: What is the URL to get to this dashboard?

Answer (score 9):

For everyone that have this issue, for now, you'll need to add any service to your app at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config

In my case I have added admob (already have analytics and gcm) and then the file was generated with api_key.

I think's it's a bug and will be soon fixed, until that, do it.

Comment: indeed there's a bug...i had to add app invites too to get new json

Comment: hi, i added the new config, but the IDE is still complaining that it is missing api_key

Comment: Before you open the IDE you can check the config file to make sure there`s 'api_key' value. Clearly there`s a bug, so we need to try different approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: does that mean, everytime I add a new dependency in my gradle file, I have to download a new google-services.json since it generates a new api_key ?

Answer (score 8):

Although Jozka Jozin's accepted answer and its comments, Cloud Messaging is neither related nor required.

Nevertheless, re-generating **`google-services.json`** is the key to solution (so I voted him). Below is what I did:

As you know you can generate the config file for Analytics from the [Google Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#get-config).

1: Choose your app.

[image: 1) choose an app]

2: Close the popup! It hides...

[image: Close the popup!]

3: **THE OPTION OF ADMOB!**

[image: the hidden option of admob]

4： Of course, select and enable it!

[image: enable it!]

5: Now we can rightly generate configuration files!

[image: generate configuration files]

6: We made it! This time, the configuration file should include the **api_key** appropriately.

[image: we made it!]

**Conclusion:** The UI of the interactive generation tool is a bit confusing...

Comment: thanks, I was able to get the new config, but the IDE is still complaining that it is missing api_key

Comment: A *bit* confusing... It is horrific!!! Kudos for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can download the `google-services.json` file again.

Steps to download:

1). Click on the top menu in your app in the `Firebase` Console.

2). Click on manage.

3). You will find `Download the latest config` file option, download and replace the `google-services.json` file in your application.

Answer (score 4):

First in your JSON file

Replace

```
"api_key": []
```

with

```
"api_key": [{ "current_key": "" }]
```

Then the gradle build will be successful but when you run your application you may get errors like the following..

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
    File2: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
    File3: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
```

To fix this issue you can add the following to your app.gradle file.. It worked for me.

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
```

Edit:
It showed me some error later while building the apk file. So I had to download the json file again. After 2 trial I got the json file with a valid api key.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using Firebase, the correct link to generate the google-services.json config file is actually found [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android).

Answer (score 2):

regenerate google-services.json at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config,**one important thing is that you must enable Cloud Messaging in "Choose services" step** ,open the new google-services.json file you will see words like

```
    "api_key": [
     {
       "current_key": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
     }"
```

without this words or without value of current_key is not the right file

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem with these steps that are not answered here. This answer is NOT enabling Cloud Messaging, it is only retrieving its server key.

So first, go to Firebase Console, and then go to Project Settings, and then click on the tab "Cloud Messaging". Look where it says "server key" and if there is no long key displaying (not the "Sender ID" number) click "Regenerate Key" and a long key should now show. Copy that key and place it in your google-services.json file at: `"api_key": [ {"current_key" : "key goes here"} ]`.

This method helped me while none of the others were working, so hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Click on Overview -> Gear icon -> Project settings.

[image]

Go to Download latest config and Click on google-service.json button to download file and save it to app folder and Compile again. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SHA certificate fingerprints to your project and then download the google-services.jason file again, which should contain "api_key": [{ "current_key": "xxxxxx" }] automatically.

You can view following page to see how to generate the fingerprints:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

On windows, just execute following command, and use android as password for debug purpose:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using Firebase

```
GoogleServices'. > Missing api_key/current_key object
```

I got this error after updating an existing project to the new Firebase Services.
The generated **google-service.json** file downloaded from the [firebase project settings page](https://console.firebase.google.com/) did not include the `api_key` needed.

> From the other answers here it looks like Google/[Firebase Cloud
>   Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (GCM/FCM) needs to be added for this `api_key` to be included
>   in the `google-service.json` file.

So I added a dependencies on the firebase FCM before downloading the file again, and this time the key was included.

Include FCM (GCM)

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reconfigure and download the `google-services.json` file then you can fetch the api key directly from firebase console. Just go to

> Overview > Add another App > Web

You will get configuration for your database which will contain `apiKey`. Just copy that value and place it in the `current_key` value denoted by XXX below

```
"api_key": [{ "current_key": "XXX" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

For firebase migrators:

make sure you have added at least one Fingerprint in your project settings and re-download the google-services.json file

Comment: Thanks man, I went as per code lab instructions and did not add SHA1 key at first. Later I had to add as my ApiKey - CurrentKey was missing. Not sure if that was the case or not. But it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebaes, you have to copy serverKey from the firebase to the google-services.json

```
 "api_key": [{ "current_key": "SERVER_KEY"}
```

To get the server Key, Goto ProjectOverview> Project Settings > CloudMessaging > Copy OR generate and copy serverKey..

Answer (score 0):

add this into your google-service.json file . you will find it under app/google-service.json

"api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": " your-google-api-key"
    }]