# Missing API Firebase Error in Android

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I added the `google-services.json` file in my android project. Then added the respective dependecies. But when sync the project I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing api_key/current_key object
```

After searching on google I found 
[Missing api_key/current key with Google Services 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317295/missing-api-key-current-key-with-google-services-3-0-0)

But that solution is not working for me. The gradle building is getting succesfull, but when I run the app I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
    File2: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
    File3: C:\Users\bucky\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
```

Comment: try clean, rebuild

Comment: not working @HristoStoyanov

Comment: show the content of app's `build.gradle`