# Android Gradle build failed - Java finished with non zero exit 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I'm trying to develop an app with Android Studio. Everything was working fine. Then I wanted to run my app on the Virtual Device just as I did a few minutes before but it failed at synchronizing the Gradle build:

> Error:Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0
>       Install Repository and sync project
> Open
>   File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

This is my Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {   
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my Module Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stefan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2')
    compile project(':org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2')

    compile project(':android-beacon-library-2.8.1')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So I researched and tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37312564/6256209
and changed `com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6` to `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`

After that my Gradle Build would sync just fine within 5 seconds or so.

But it fails If I want to run it on the Virtual Device.
It gives me 4 Errors:

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 2

All of them ending with finished with non-zero exit value.

So I found this: [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29756188/6256209)

And I tried to set multiDexEnabled to true and checked if I included unnecessary libs. I also clean and rebuild the app but nothing worked.

I'm really thankfull for any kind of help and advice

Comment: Perhaps worth a look at..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Comment: No sadly not. I started a new Project and did everything the same way and it works.

Answer (score 2):

At First you should call this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
```

> The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools
>   21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android
>   Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager before
>   attempting to configure your app for multidex.

Then add  **multiDexEnabled true**

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Finally **Clean-Rebuild-Sync-Run** .

Comment: let me feedback please .

Comment: I will. But the Gradle is building up now for 15 min. I'll let you know the result as soon as it is done.

Comment: @nummer92 okay . as your wish . hope this process help you .

Comment: Nope no success. It brought 8 Errors up and then Android studio crashed

Answer (score 0):

SO these are the 8 new Errors:

> Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>
> Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>
> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3
>
> Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3
>
> Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3
>
> Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3
>   Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3