# Gradle cannot find dependency that doesn't exist - Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to import an android project from bitbucket at my work, as the former android developer quit and I'm to continue his work.

Gradle sync never returns ok. It got the error:

> Error:Could not find
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0. Required by:
>       frontend:app:unspecified

funny thing is, I grabbed every occourence of the string "measurement" at the whole git folder and found only one, at module app, build.gradle, and it was commented and not even the version gradle is complaining about:

```
dependencies {
...
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0'
...
}
```

Can someone please help? I would really appriciate it as I'm struggling here for a couple of hours already.
Thx in advance!

the project (named "frontend") build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the module (named "app") build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartbus"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 29
        versionName "2.1.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}


retrolambda {
    jdk "C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe"
    jvmArgs '-noverify' }





dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0'
    retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the whole-error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. Could not resolve
>   all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. Could not
>   find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.jar
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.jar
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom
>            https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Re'em/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Re'em/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Re'em/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Re'em/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement/9.0.0/play-services-measurement-9.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            frontend:app:unspecified

Comment: Can u post your build.gradle?

Comment: I've just noticed that the com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0 doesn't exist. Check app:dependencies to get the dependencies tree.

Comment: What is your gms version?

Comment: Measurements is not a library in the play services, so what are you trying to include?  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Raghavendra - it's com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3 
(according to build.gradle of project). I tried insert there some prev version and android wanted to auto-correct me back to this version so I guess it's installed on my machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade to Google Play Services:9.0.0 Error Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi)

Comment: @Re'em please try with the latest gms version.

Comment: @Re'em is that worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3' to the latest version say 
classpath  'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and check

courtesy [user3330522 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi)

Comment: now gradle finds another problem, but this one is solved. thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped! What is the another problem?