# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to install new firebase database into my app, but it was failed with next error:

> Error:Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0. Required
>   by:
>       appName:app:unspecified

than i clone official google example frome [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) and was trying to build database example, but i still get same error...

looks like this is because of some google error. am i right? 
in other case, why it happens and how to fix this?

Comment: check logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi/37406307#37406307

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to update/install Google Repository, revision 30 (Your android studio latest version).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the project, Just add google services dependency to you root level gradle `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`
and firebase database dependency to your app level gradle `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'`

Answer (score 0):

The part I was missing was in by build.gradle (Project:). Make sure this is there:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

It allows the project to find it in Google's Maven repository.