# Error:(29, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12 Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, junit

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and it is giving error "Error:(29, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12" Similar error for any third party library. I have tried removing and adding the junit library from Project Settings but still it giving same error. I'm not sure whether this proxy issue? I have checked connection from Studio for maven link and it is showing successful.  Following is my **build.gradle**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

Project Level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something and how to resolve this.

Comment: for test case `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"` then `targetSdkVersion 23` then `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`

Comment: finally `clean-rebuild-gradle`

Comment: show your `build.gradle` project level

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12

Comment: Followed you instruction got following error: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'. Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi/37406307#37406307 add just `task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

Comment: It is already there

Answer (score 0):

After lot of efforts I was able to resolve this issue. Issue lies with the proxy settings, I have added following lines in gradle.properties file and gradle synced successfully with dependencies resolved

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=x.x.x.x
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx
```