# Duplicate Entry for ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am Importing my project from Eclipse , while building an APK i found following Error.

Error:Execution failed for task

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener.class

Error:Execution failed for task ':gruhini:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/games/Game.class

Error:Execution failed for task ':gruhini:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException.class

Error:Execution failed for task ':gruhini:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

my build.gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
           compileSdkVersion 24
           buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
           useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/**'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gruhini"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    preDexLibraries false
    //javaMaxHeapSize "1G" // 2g should be also OK
      }
      }

     dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile project(':eclipseProject')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

  }
```

Comment: try this for your code android{


    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
]

Comment: you add google-play-services.jar as well as com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0

Comment: I tried to hide the code of compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') . Still it reflects the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/plus/

**Problem**

```
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar') // Remove this line
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' //10.0.1 or 9.6.0
```

Both are same .Call one of them .
Then **Clean-Rebuild and Run** .

Try with this **App Level** `build.gradle`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gruhini"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':eclipseProject')
        compile files('libs/activation.jar')
        compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/mail.jar')
        compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

}
```

**Project Level** `build.gradle`

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' //2.2.3
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I removed that line , clean the project , rebuild project and while generating the apk same error found :(

Comment: @KevalShukla Restart your IDE

Comment: @KevalShukla same problem ??

Comment: While downgrading the version of gms playservice(8.4.0) i found folllowing error .                                                                                                                   Error:Execution failed for task ':gruhini:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/games/Game.class

Comment: @KevalShukla call `9.6.0`

Comment: By adding gms playservice (9.6.0) it found another error  . Which i will add in the question tag .

Comment: When i add this line : apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
i found an error . I added that error in my question tag .

Comment: @KevalShukla add `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1` my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37406307/3395198

Comment: I use your dependencies in both file API level and Project Level  . Now it reflects to the very first error that i have faced . :(

Comment: Could you please provide another solution.? @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 0):

Do inside Android in your gradle file like this.

```
   android{
    configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

instead of you write inside dex option.

your gradle file will looks like..

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
     android {
               compileSdkVersion 24
               buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
               useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
configurations {
                all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
        }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/**'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gruhini"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries false
        //javaMaxHeapSize "1G" // 2g should be also OK
          }
          }

         dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {

    })
    compile project(':eclipseProject')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works Properly by Removing Following Lines from Gradle .                 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the **play-services versions** being used in your packages (i.e. a package using version x, another package using version y).

None of the other answers explain why you should use play-services version `x.y.z` or how to check which one is applicable. You can check that with **`./gradlew :app:dependencies`**

You will get an output similar to

```
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.6 --> (11.0.1)(*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1 (*)
```

```

From this output you can see the **latest version of play-services** being used in your project (in the above example it's 11.0.1).
In your **`build.gradle`** file, you should specify this version for all play-services (they all must be the same version).