# Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-location-services

**Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4]**

**Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4]**

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i used android studio 2.3.2 version my project build successfully but after updated to android studio version to 2.3.3 and updated google play services i am getting this error please help.

There is no play-services-basement and play-services-tasks folder in my folder

**when i comment this "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'" line my project compiling fine if i uncomment then my project not compiling**

Project Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {

    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 25
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

}


repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.beyka:androidtiffbitmapfactory:0.9.6.2'

    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

}
```

[image]

Comment: "install repository and sync project" try that maybe

Comment: i clicked install but nothing happended

Comment: go to sdk manager and install manually

Comment: Tim Castelijns there is no folder in my sdk path. please tell me how to do manually?

Comment: when i comment this "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'" line my project run fine if i uncomment then my project not compiling

Comment: You require the Google Repo in the Gradle file. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: However, that `ResourceException` hints that you are behind a firewall that is preventing your internet access

Comment: @cricket_007 i will check and come back sir. One more doubt google() this is google repo right?

Comment: It is, but you need Gradle version 4.x for that

Comment: @cricket_007 ok sir i update to latest gradle 4.2 then check and come back

Comment: You don't need `google()`... You can give the actual `maven{}` location

Comment: @cricket_007  ok sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade to Google Play Services:9.0.0 Error Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311794/upgrade-to-google-play-services9-0-0-error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-androi)

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() 
        maven {
         url 'https://maven.google.com'    
       }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'    
       }
  }
}
```